# How can I use SCSS mixins, to improve media queries?

Tags: sass

I'm in the middle of a refactoring and trying to improve the ***media queries*** of the grid classes.

I'm using ***variables***, ***interpolation*** and ***mixins***, but I think the code could be improved.

This is what I have:

```
$small: 576px;
$medium: 768px;
$large: 992px;

@mixin col($number){
   width: #{100% / (12 / $number)};
   padding-right: 1rem;
   padding-left: 1rem;
}


@for $i from 1 through 12{
  .col-#{$i} {
    @include col($i);     
   }
}

@media (max-width: $small){
  @for $i from 1 through 12{
     .col-#{$i}-s {
       @include col($i);   
     }
  }
}
@media (max-width: $medium){
  @for $i from 1 through 12{
     .col-#{$i}-m {
       @include col($i); 
     }
  }
}
@media (max-width: $large){
  @for $i from 1 through 12{
     .col-#{$i}-l {
       @include col($i);     
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What happened to my answer? Didn’t solved your problem? Maybe i can improve it to fit your needs.

Comment: @muecas I used the inspector to check the column’s classes and I noticed that they were repeated many times because the for was inside the each. Sorry :(

Comment: I do not understand your point. If you want to build a responsive grid, then you need to repeat each set of columns for each desired breakpoint. I think there is no other way to achive that. Your code will produce exactly the same CSS output as the on i proposed. Also i will like to know what would be the expected output, and what you call "column classes repeated". Thanks!

Comment: For example the col-2-m class si repested 6 times, the same number of elements $breakpoints has

Comment: In the output? Check it: it has `.col-6`, `.col-6-s`, `.col-6-m` and `.col-6-l`. Each column name is written only once, none of them are repeated. You can check that with a simple find.

Comment: Paste the proposed code [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/) to check its output if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your code by reducing and automating the build of media queries.

THe code will define the maximum number of columns to use (`$grid-columns`) and then will iterate thru all defined breakpoint (`$breakpoints`). The default columns will be nested in a default media query that will match all breakpoint (using `min-width: 0px`). SO for each breakpoint and each columns, the new mixin will print the selector for each column, calculating its width according to the maximum columns for the grid.

Feel free to change the breakpoint names, their max width, or add new breakpoints. The only required breakpoint will be the default one.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Now the code has two `@mixin`, one for writing breakpoints and the other to write columns.

```
// Define all the breakpoints as a set of lists
// First breakpoint will be the default breakpoint, ass as many as you want
$breakpoints : (
    'default' 0px,
    's'       576px,
    'm'       768px,
    'l'       992px
) !default;

// Max number of columns
$grid-columns : 12 !default;

// Column writing
@mixin col($columns, $breakpoint, $max: $grid-columns) {

    // Set the class specific breakpont identifier os none for default breakpoint
    $prefix : unquote(if($breakpoint != 'default', '-#{$breakpoint}', ''));

    // COlumn styles
    .col-#{$columns}#{$prefix} {
        width: (100% / $max) * $columns;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

}

// Media query writing
@mixin breakpoint($breakpoint, $max: $grid-columns) {

    // Sets the condition for the media query, default w
    $condition : if(nth($breakpoint, 1) == 'default', min-width, max-width);

    // Media query for the breakpoint
    @media screen and (#{$condition}: nth($breakpoint, 2)) {

        // For each column 1 to $columns
        @for $i from 1 through $max {

            // Build the column
            @include col($i, nth($breakpoint, 1), $max);

        }

    }

}

// For each defined breakpoint
@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {

    // Creates the breakpoint
    @include breakpoint($breakpoint);

}
```

Will output:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
    .col-1 {
        width: 8.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-2 {
        width: 16.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-3 {
        width: 25%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-4 {
        width: 33.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-5 {
        width: 41.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-6 {
        width: 50%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-7 {
        width: 58.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-8 {
        width: 66.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-9 {
        width: 75%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-10 {
        width: 83.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-11 {
        width: 91.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-12 {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .col-1-s {
        width: 8.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-2-s {
        width: 16.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-3-s {
        width: 25%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-4-s {
        width: 33.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-5-s {
        width: 41.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-6-s {
        width: 50%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-7-s {
        width: 58.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-8-s {
        width: 66.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-9-s {
        width: 75%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-10-s {
        width: 83.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-11-s {
        width: 91.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-12-s {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-1-m {
        width: 8.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-2-m {
        width: 16.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-3-m {
        width: 25%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-4-m {
        width: 33.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-5-m {
        width: 41.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-6-m {
        width: 50%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-7-m {
        width: 58.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-8-m {
        width: 66.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-9-m {
        width: 75%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-10-m {
        width: 83.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-11-m {
        width: 91.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-12-m {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .col-1-l {
        width: 8.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-2-l {
        width: 16.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-3-l {
        width: 25%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-4-l {
        width: 33.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-5-l {
        width: 41.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-6-l {
        width: 50%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-7-l {
        width: 58.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-8-l {
        width: 66.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-9-l {
        width: 75%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-10-l {
        width: 83.33333%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-11-l {
        width: 91.66667%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-12-l {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
}
```